# Vim colorize cpp in pure color scheme

Tags: c++, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I use default color schemes (with my little changes) and no plugins for coloring.

Unfortunately now I need to work on remote machine (using Putty) where I can't use 256 color mode. And this looks pure.

[image]

I try to fix it, but I can't understand what is the highlight name of different parts. I tried to use this macro and it helps slightly. (I took it from there http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor)

```
map <F10> :echo "hi<" . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name") . '> trans<'
\ . synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),0),"name") . "> lo<"
\ . synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."),col("."),1)),"name") . ">"<CR>
```

The most frequent macros output is `hi<> trans<cBlock> lo<>` and `hi<> trans<cParen> lo<>`.

My main goal - colorize such stuff like operators (`<` `!=` `&` etc), figured brackets `{`, `}`, `::` and `.`.  I tried to read pure `:hi` output and change something based on name (like `cBracket`) but this don't work.

Can someone refer me to manual about syntax highlighting in case of cpp + vim, or show me the right way to solve this?

Comment: Is there some specific reason you can't use 256 colors with PuTTy?  Setting `TERM=xterm-256color` always worked for me back when I used PuTTy.  Actually I think PuTTy has a setting to enable 256 colors as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not defining your own syntax ?

```
syn match myOperators /[><&(etc)]/
hi myOperators ctermfg=green
```

:h syn-match